# What is difference between $i=\overline{1,n}$ and $i \in \overline{1,n}$

Tags: notation

I've seen different versions for enumeration $1,2,3,...,n, \;\;n\in\mathbb{N}$, but what's the difference between $i=\overline{1,n}$ and $i \in \overline{1,n}$?

Comment: Sometimes notations are uncommon or get used different ways in different places... so it might help folks to answer your question if you mention the book/website/pdf/etc. where you found this particular notation.

Comment: No idea.  I have no idea what either means and different texts have different notations.  But $i = whatever$ means $1$ and $whatever$ are the same thing.  $i \in whatever$ means $whatever$ is a set of elements and $i$ is one of them.

Comment: Where are you seeing this notation? Seems like terrible notation.

Comment: @fleablood "... for $i=1,2,\dots,n$" doesn't mean that, though. Seems like that might be what is meant here, but very hard to tell without context.

Comment: My guess, and it *is* a guess is that $\overline{1,n}$ is the set of all natural numbers from $1$ to $n$.  So $i = \overline{1,n}$ would mean that $i$ is a label to identify the entire set as a set.  $i \in  \overline{1,n}$ would mean that $i$ is a member of the set, or in other words, $i$ is a natural number between $1$ and $n$.

Comment: Even under your assumption, I would take the $i=$ case to mean the same thing as $i\in$ case, if the variable is really $i.$ Sloppy notation, but it would be a terrible mathematics book/paper to use $i$ to mean a set. You are technically correct, but probably wrong about the author's intent. @fleablood

Comment: @ThomasAndrews ooh, very good point and yes you are probably correct.  I change me mind.  I am *now* guessing that that $i = \overline{1,n}$ means what I have more commonly seen as $i=1,.....,n$ (which is technically incorrect but is common shortcut) meaning $i$ is a natural number between $1$ to $n$.  The other way to write the exact same thing is $i \in \{1,.....,n\}$.  I guess the book considered $\overline{1,n}$ to be acceptable shorthand $\{1,,...n\}$ and so the two are the same. Neither are technically correct but could be used shorthand.

Comment: " but it would be a terrible mathematics book/paper to use i to mean a set."  I whole heartedly agree.  There variable $i$ is traditionally for natural numbers and capital letters are for sets this is only a convention.  You are probably correct about the author's intent. @ThomasAndrews

Comment: In my opinion:  I would *never* use the $\in$ sign unless what follows is either a well and correctly defined set or a variable for a previously established set. i.e. I'd never use $\in$ sloppily.  However I have frequently and would use the $=$ sloppily and could us $i = some\ expression$ to mean "imagine the listed items in the expressions as a set; $i$ is one of the elements".  (but that *is* sloppy)

Comment: For example, I've seen deffinition of matrix like this:

> ${\displaystyle A=\left(a_{ij}\right),\!}$ where ${\displaystyle i={\overline {1,m}}\!}\;$ and ${\displaystyle j={\overline {1,n}}.\!}$

Comment: @fleablood, I know this is all conjecture, but my guess would be the same as what I think Thomas Andrews suggested... that $i$ takes on each value from $1$ to $n$, as opposed to ***one*** of those numbers.

Comment: @MathLearner, in that example, I think the author is trying to convey that $A$ is a matrix which has elements $a_{ij}$ for ***every*** value of $i$ from 1 to $m$ and value of $j$ from 1 to $n$, as opposed to one specific value for $i$ and another specific value for $j$.

Comment: So, I think $i=\overline{1,n} \iff \forall i\in\overline{1,n} \iff \forall i \in {\{1,2,...,n\}}$ ?

Comment: So now you're abusing $\Longleftrightarrow$. My guess for the intended meaning would be something like$$\sum_{i=\overline{1,n}}^{  } i = \sum_{i=1}^{ n } i$$Of course, that's without any context. Ideally, the author would define their use of that notation.

Comment: I think a hidden $\forall$ is highly unlikely, but a pure English "for all" is likely. There is a difference between $\forall$ and the words "for all." $\forall$ is formal notation, and not all occurrences of "for all" can be repllaces with $\forall.$ @MathLearne

Comment: For example, if I say, "Let $b_i=a_{n+1-i}$ for all $i=1,\dots,n,$" it is not correct to replace "for all" here with $\forall.$ (You may sometimes see professors do so on a blackboard, but that is just a shorthand because writing all the words takes more time and blackboard space.)